# How can I check if Java is installed on my Mac?

Tags: macos, java

I have gone into Terminal and typed

```
java -v
```

for which it responds with

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

But I am not sure if that is confirming if Java is not installed or whether the Java SDK is not installed.

Comment: Did you install Java from [here](http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=225346_090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135)?

Comment: Are you trying to check if the JDK or JRE is installed?

Answer (score 1):

If it's responding with `No Java runtime present, requesting install.`... well, it's not installed. I believe that Apple's default installer still installs Java 6; I'd recommend getting the latest version (right now Java 8u144) from [here.](https://java.com/en/download/)

With Java 8, `java -v` fails with `Unrecognized option: -v.` Use `java -version` instead.

Comment: I think that link is for browser only try http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: @Mark Don't think so, should be the JRE. Not 100% tho.

Answer (score 0):

Many versions of Java for macOS install an entry into the System Preferences. If you have a Java icon in System Preferences, it's highly likely that Java is installed on the Mac:

[image]

Comment: That is only for the JRE used in a browser

Comment: @Mark, I have the full Java 8 JRE installed on my Mac (not just browser support). The Java system preference pane shows up as part of the install. So, the system preference pane is included with Java installations that cover more than just the browser.

Comment: I think that panel only covers the browser install - look at the settings in it. Also the Java JRE for OSX does not support the command line. I think you have to install the full JDK (although there might be a version in between)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following path:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
You can also use the find command to scan you system.
In you terminal execute 
sudo find / -name "java" 2>/dev/null
You will then find where in your computer there is a java file.